# Creating a website

Tags: web-development, website-design, personal-website

I am considering creating a website. It should be something basic where I can click on a button and then it sends me to another link on the page and where I can put text... What tool should I use? Which programing language?

Comment: This is far too broad to answer on a Q&A site such as this. Google is your friend here. Avoid Microsoft sites like the plague.

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic here.

Comment: Ohh... Ok sorry I didn't know

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should look at [sites.google.com](http://sites.google.com) or [webs.com](http://www.webs.com) also there are lot more. Try googling it and you found many hosting sites. Also if you planning for blog you can try [blogger.com](http://blogger.com)